# MongoDB - How to remove part of string in field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have several documents, I want to remove the alphabet from the `data` field, based on the 1st `_` in the `data` field, please see the following output. and if the data is empty the get message "Not Auto found".

```
[
  {
    "data": "ABCS_auto"
  },
  {
    "data": "TRQWEY_car_2"
  },
  {
    "data": "ALPHAB1234RAVO_Garie_2__4_22__11"
  },
  {
    "data": ""
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "data": "auto"
  },
  {
    "data": "car_2"
  },
  {
    "data": "Garie_2__4_22__11"
  },
  {
    "data": "No Auto found"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `$set` - Set `split_data` field:

   1.1. If `data` not empty string, then split by "_" and return array.

   1.2. Else return empty array.
2. `$project` - Decorate output document.

   2.1. If `split_data` is not empty array, then

   2.1.1. `$trim` starting "_" from the result 2.1.1.1.

   2.1.1.1. With `$reduce`, concatenate string with "_" from the result remove the first item from `split_data`.

   2.2. Else default message.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      split_data: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $not: {
              $or: [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$data",
                    null
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$data",
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          then: {
            $split: [
              "$data",
              "_"
            ]
          },
          else: []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $not: {
              $eq: [
                "$split_data",
                []
              ]
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "$trim": {
              "input": {
                $reduce: {
                  input: {
                    "$slice": [
                      "$split_data",
                      1,
                      {
                        $size: "$split_data"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  initialValue: "",
                  in: {
                    $concat: [
                      "$$value",
                      "_",
                      "$$this"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              "chars": "_"
            }
          },
          "else": "No auto found"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mZmteU3g0B7)

---

Another approach I think is much easier is with `$regexFind`:

1. `$set` - Create `data_regex` field with regex match object by searching "_ .*" (Mean string starting with "_" and any other character(s)).
2. `$project` - Decorate output document.

   2.1. Trim the "_" from `data_regex.match`.

   2.2. Else default message.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      data_regex: {
        $regexFind: {
          input: "$data",
          regex: "_.*"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $not: {
              $eq: [
                "$data_regex",
                null
              ]
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "$trim": {
              "input": "$data_regex.match",
              "chars": "_"
            }
          },
          "else": "No auto found"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (`$regexFind`)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6gLdjYrqmQD)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$project: {data: {$arrayElemAt:[{ $split:["$data","_"]},1]}}}])
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, but it remove all the ´_´ from the string

Answer (score 0):

Use [$ifNull](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) for "No Auto Found" and [$split](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) for "_"

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              {
                $split: [
                  "$data",
                  "_"
                ]
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          "No Auto found"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

here is a working [mongoplayground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dNmhtXysOsp)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but see the output of the 2nd object data, it contain 2 "_" and I need the output with car_2, but in your case , just getting car

Comment: Oh ok, I will check that

Comment: just want to remove the first "_" from the string, after the first "_" want to keep remaining string, whatever it will contain